# sMail server cannot get connect by Linux frequently

Tags: linux, networking, email

[image]
I have a mail server A build by `iredmail` on Centos6.5 system. The mail server have a public ip aaa.

There are about 40~50 mail clients which operating system is windows in local network, they all NAT as public ip ccc(the router C is build by linux system). On other hand, there is few machine in the same local network use linux system. And some of them can not get connect with mail server frequently.

For example, I use a desktop with Fedora 19 to `telnet` mail server 443 port, and capture on mail server with `tcpdump` command

```
15:16:55.144222 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.46989 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.https: Flags [S], seq 939563650, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 23633360 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:17:03.160282 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.46989 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.https: Flags [S], seq 939563650, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 23641376 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

But with a windows 7 which on the same hub with Feodra 19 to telnet mail server 443 port

```
15:20:54.484991 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.49218 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.https: Flags [S], seq 31344922, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
15:20:54.485034 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.https > xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.49218: Flags [S.], seq 1361958840, ack 31344923, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:20:54.485558 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.49218 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.https: Flags [.], ack 1, win 4380, length 0
15:20:55.685554 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.https > xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.49218: Flags [S.], seq 1361958840, ack 31344923, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:20:55.686359 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.49218 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.https: Flags [.], ack 1, win 4380, options [nop,nop,sack 1 {0:1}], length 0
15:21:05.122927 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.49218 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.https: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 4380, length 0
15:21:05.123193 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.https > xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.49218: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 2, win 115, length 0
15:21:05.123813 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.49218 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.https: Flags [.], ack 2, win 4380, length 0
```

All the windows 7 and Feodra19 in the same network environment，but windows 7 always get successfully and Feodar 19 some times get failed. But when I use a linux server B which have a public ip bbb to `telnet` the mail server,and it is successfully and never get failed. I consider if it is a problem with linux connect to a same source ip.

The local network mail clients with windows usually connect to mail server to check the mail 3 mins interval. I don't know it is useful or not to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason by myself finally.
All that because of:

> net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=1

Because of windows always don't have timestamp option in the SYN package,but the Linux ones always
have timestamp option,so mail server didn't create new TCP/IP connect with request which have a wrong timestamp.